# How to config public route and auth route in gRPC gateway

Tags: go, grpc-gateway

Is there any way to config public route and auth route in gRPC gateway similar to other http frameworks. For example in `echo` framework we can config like this

```
func main() {
    e := echo.New()
    authRoute := e.Group("/auth", middlewares.Verify)
    publicRoute := e.Group("/")
    // ...
}
```

in grpc-gateway, I have config like this.

```
func run() error {
  ctx := context.Background()
  ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)
  defer cancel()

  // Register gRPC server endpoint
  // Note: Make sure the gRPC server is running properly and accessible
  mux := runtime.NewServeMux()
  opts := []grpc.DialOption{grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials())}
  err := gw.RegisterYourServiceHandlerFromEndpoint(ctx, mux,  *grpcServerEndpoint, opts)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }

  // Start HTTP server (and proxy calls to gRPC server endpoint)
  return http.ListenAndServe(":8081", mux)
}
```

Is there any way to make `mux` with authenticated decorator function for specific routes. And function `RegisterYourServiceHandlerFromEndpoint` will register it

```
authenMux := runtime.NewServeMux()
// make it with authenticated func
//....

err := gw.RegisterYourServiceHandlerFromEndpoint(ctx, authenMux,  *grpcServerEndpoint, opts)
```

Comment: what do you mean by grpc gateway?

Comment: i use grpc-gateway. I wonder if there is a way to add 1 route with middleware verifier and add another public route

Comment: "See [a_bit_of_everything.proto](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/blob/18c472a4af4f19948a247b28d9411cf85776ba22/examples/internal/proto/examplepb/a_bit_of_everything.proto#L567) for examples of more annotations you can add to customize gateway behavior and generated OpenAPI output."

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure about your specific goal, but if you only want to customize the gRPC-gateway, you can follow this approach. Alternatively, you can transfer the logic to a separate function.

```
// run starts the HTTP server and sets up a custom gRPC-gateway route.
// It registers the gRPC server endpoint and a custom POST route ("/auth").
func run() error {
    // Create a background context and cancel function for graceful shutdown
    ctx := context.Background()
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)
    defer cancel()

    // Create a gRPC-gateway multiplexer
    mux := runtime.NewServeMux()

    // Register gRPC server endpoint with insecure transport credentials
    opts := []grpc.DialOption{grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials())}
    err := gw.RegisterYourServiceHandlerFromEndpoint(ctx, mux, *grpcServerEndpoint, opts)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Handle custom POST route ("/auth")
    err = mux.HandlePath("POST", "/auth", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, pathParams map[string]string) {
        // Create a map with the desired data
        responseData := map[string]string{
            "data": "something",
        }

        // Convert the map to a JSON string
        resp, err := json.Marshal(responseData)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, "Error encoding JSON", http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }

        // Set the Content-Type header to application/json
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

        // Write the JSON response to the response writer
        w.Write(resp)
    })

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Start HTTP server (and proxy calls to gRPC server endpoint)
    return http.ListenAndServe(":8081", mux)
}
```

Comment: in this var mux := runtime.NewServeMux(). Is there any similar way we can create an auth mux